# Mongoose findOne as : Array = [FindOne , FindOne, FindOne ,FindOne, FindOne...] , Using ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I have user login have the special _id, then when doing any activate in the web app, like pass some exam or upload anything will add as database with the `iduse` 
what `iduse` mean ? : for my app any Schema has an `iduse` with the original _id. that just for knew the user and what you doing in the app web. Okay new I wanna to find all the same iduse with `findOne` keywork. in mongoose :

```
    var iduser = current.id.user //that mean the _id of user who login 
    var something = await storescors16.findOne({ iduser })
```

as you know I have more than one iduser. and I wanna to find it with the `findOne` keyword in mongoose.

output as :

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("616ad9b3bc8e8dkjfbvoue"),
  iduser: ' 616ab2006cb743bc31bf2590',
  level: '3',
  day: 'some',
  date: '2021-10-13',
  time: '7 : 30',
  objectif: 'something ',
  __v: 0
}

{
  _id: new ObjectId("616ad9b3b52942942484bvoueq49"),
  iduser: ' 616ab2006cb743bc31bf2590',
  level: '3',
  day: 'some',
  date: '2021-10-13',
  time: '7 : 30',
  objectif: 'something ',
  __v: 0
}

{
  _id: new ObjectId("616ad9b3hbdfiw5169333333jfbvoueq9c"),
  iduser: ' 616ab2006cb743bc31bf2590',
  level: '3',
  day: 'some',
  date: '2021-10-13',
  time: '7 : 30',
  objectif: 'something ',
  __v: 0
}


{
  _id: new ObjectId("611111111111doufbwoeurgbu6"),
  iduser: ' 616ab2006cb743bc31bf2590',
  level: '3',
  day: 'some',
  date: '2021-10-13',
  time: '7 : 30',
  objectif: 'something ',
  __v: 0
}
```

NodeJs for get data

```
router.get('/result', auth, async(req, res) => {
  
    var ids = req.session.user._id

    var points = await model.findOne({ ids })

    res.render('./options/result', {
        notes: ponts,
    })
});
```

And for display it use ejs :

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) { %>
                    <div class="child">
                        <div class="itms sld1">
                            <%=notes.objectif%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="itms sld">
                            <%=notes.time%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="itms sld">
                            <span>
                                <%=notes[i].date%>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="itms sld">
                            <%=notes[i].day%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="itms sld">
                            <%=notes[i].level%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

As the name says `findOne` will actually return exactly one document, which will be the first document that matches your criteria in the list.

If you want to get an array of documents use `find` method :)

```
var points = await model.find({ iduser: ids })
```

Comment: that return no thing !

Comment: Probably used the wrong field. I have updated the comment. Try again.